# Post action option for SQL*Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

In my project, we are using SQL*Loader for loading a set of data. If this load is successful we want to execute another SQL instruction. Does SQL*Loader have any option for that?

Comment: How do you execute the sqlloader command? I guess it will be from some kind of command line (e.g. UNIX)? If so, you can test for the exit code to see if it was successful. For example if [ $? -eq 0 ]  in UNIX.

Comment: Hi!, I'm using a UNIX Script. Thx u!

Comment: So, you can go with the approach suggested i.e, if [ $? -eq 0 ]  do the next load else fail

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any inbuilt feature to do things on success, rather you can write a wrapper to do so. The return codes come handy here

[For Linux and UNIX operating systems, the exit codes are as follows:](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-FDC9B490-7C23-4DEF-B826-9FDAEAF0FA64.htm#SUTIL1048)

```
EX_SUCC 0
EX_FAIL 1
EX_WARN 2
EX_FTL  3
```

For Windows operating systems, the exit codes are as follows:

```
EX_SUCC 0
EX_FAIL 1
EX_WARN 2
EX_FTL  4
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach could be to use an external table instead of SQL Loader. Then you could write the whole logic in PL/SQL.